# react-native-streetview not working in IOS

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-streetview library to load street view in my app. But it shows only black screen. Can anyone please help me with where I am going wrong.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
            <StreetView
                style={styles.streetView}
                allGesturesEnabled={true}
                coordinate={{
                    'latitude': -33.852,
                    'longitude': 151.211

                }}
            />
</View>
```

PS: I am using react-navigation library in my app.

Comment: did you resolve your issue? I’m facing the same thing.

Comment: @ChrisEdwards no not yet..haven't got any solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using my fork https://github.com/chrise86/react-native-streetview.

I've changed the way the coordinate is loaded in the native bridge. I also specify `heading` prop on my `<Streetview />` component:

```
<StreetView
  style={styles.streetView}
  allGesturesEnabled={true}
  coordinate={{ latitude, longitude }}
  heading={180}
  onSuccess={() => console.log('map loaded')}
  onError={(event) => console.log('failed to load map', event.nativeEvent)}
/>
```

Comment: This has been added to the main repo in this commit: https://github.com/nesterapp/react-native-streetview/commit/4796117316d022fe1f765e2f0238569ea167387a

But the npm package hasn't been updated. So it might make more sense to install from Git URL rather than npm package name.